# Java Concurrency: Find task failed in a pool of tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Following [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) shows fetching records from a server(say). `ExecutorService` is used to create a `ThreadPool` of 2 threads and I have invoked all these threads with `Timeout` of 3 seconds. 
Intentionally I made some tasks to fail.

**Now my question is, how to get the EmpID's of the tasks which failed?**

MainClass:

```
public class MultiThreadEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] empIDArray = {
                "100", "200", "300", "400", "500", 
                "600", "700", "800", "900", "1000", 
                "1100", "1200", "1300", "1400", "1500"
            };

        List<ThreadTaskEach> taskList = new ArrayList<ThreadTaskEach>();
        try {
            for(String empID : empIDArray) {
                taskList.add(new ThreadTaskEach(empID));
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        List<Future<Map<String, String>>> futureList = null;
        try {
            ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
            futureList = service.invokeAll(taskList, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            service.shutdown();
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured: " + ie.getMessage());
        }

        for(Future<Map<String, String>> future : futureList) {
            try {
                Map<String, String> resultMap = future.get();

                for(String key : resultMap.keySet()) {
                    System.out.println(resultMap.get(key));
                }

            } catch(ExecutionException ee) {
                System.out.println("Exception occured: " + ee.getMessage());
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                System.out.println("Exception occured: " + ie.getMessage());
            } catch(CancellationException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception occured: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Thread class

```
class ThreadTaskEach implements Callable<Map<String, String>>{

    private String empID;

    public ThreadTaskEach(String empID) {
        this.empID = empID;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> call() throws Exception {
        try {
            return prepareMap(empID);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured: " + e.getMessage());
            throw new Exception("Exception occured: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private Map<String, String> prepareMap(String empID) throws InterruptedException {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        if(Integer.parseInt(empID) % 500 == 0) {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }

        map.put(empID, empID + ": " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

        return map;
    }
}
```

In the above code 500, 1000 .. fails to complete within 3 seconds.

```
Map<String, String> resultMap = future.get();
```

So when I say future.get() for these tasks I am getting `CancellationException`. But how to get the EmpID from the task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `invokeAll`, you could `submit` each task one by one and store each future in a map:

```
Future<?> f = executor.submit(task);
map.put(f, task.getId());
```

Now when you try to get, if you have an exception, you can use the map to go back to the id. However you would need to put a timeout on each `future.get()` which is maybe not practical for your use case.

The alternative is to use the specification of `invokeAll` [which guarantees to return the futures in the same order as the tasks that were submitted](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29).

> Returns a list of Futures representing the tasks, **in the same sequential order as produced by the iterator for the given task list**.

As long as you use a List, the iteration order is fixed and you can match the two lists:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < futureList.size(); i++) {
        Future<Map<String, String>> future = futureList.get(i)
        try {
            Map<String, String> resultMap = future.get();

            for(String key : resultMap.keySet()) {
                System.out.println(resultMap.get(key));
            }
        } catch(ExecutionException ee) {
            System.out.println("Exception in task " + taskList.get(i).getId());
        }
    }
```

Just make sure that you use a collection with a stable iteration order (ArrayList is fine).

Comment: So by using `invokeAll` you are saying that I cannot get empID from the task? Only `submit` can give me that?

Comment: @Che I'm saying that it seems simpler. `invokeAll` returns the futures in the same order as the tasks that have been submitted. So you could do it that way too (i.e. if the 6th future fails, it should correspond to the 6th task in your original list). Except that if you change your collection from a list to a set for example, the iteration order might be undefined and that could lead to bugs.

Comment: But submit method does not have a parameter for timeout rt?

Comment: @Che I have added an alternative which is probably more suited for your use case.

Comment: Actually this one has worked. But I am only worried abt `in the same sequential order as produced by the iterator for the given task list.` As far as you know is there any other approach?

Comment: @Che That is not worrying as long as you use an ArrayList. The other solution would be to use submit, and call `future.get(timeout)` on each future, except that you would need to recalculate the timeout at each iteration (not very complicated but adds more code).

Comment: Thanks. Pls one last question can we know how much time each task has taken. One method is to note down the start time and end time and return the total time. Is there any other way of getting the time from the java concurrent api's.

Comment: @Che No I think you need to calculate it yourself.